# I change a little of my code, KeyError is 0. But it cannot work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My previous code is:

```
import pandas as pd

limit = 3
G0 = 7.75e-05
v=0.1           
step_size = 2e-3
splitcounts=200


data1 = pd.read_csv(\
    'C:\\Data Analysis\\Data.txt',\
    sep=',',names=['Time1','Current','Voltage','Distance', 'Time2'])

nrows1 = data1.shape[0]

temp = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time','Current'])

 
for i,j in zip(range(0, int(nrows1)),range(0, int(splitcounts))):
  if 0<data1.at[i,'Current']<0.000075:
      temp=temp.append(data1.loc[i,0:2])
  else:
      n = temp.shape[0] 
      if n>5:
             temp.to_csv("C:\\Data Analysis\\Datas/%04d.csv" %j,\
                    sep=',',index=False, header=None)
      else:
          temp = []
```

I want to add some conditions to divide them into two folders:

```
for i in range(0, int(nrows1)):
    if 0<data1.at[i,'Current']<0.000075:
        temp = pd.DataFrame(temp)
        temp=temp.append(data1.iloc[i,0:2])
    else:
        #temp = np.array(list, dtype=float)
        temp = pd.DataFrame(temp)
        n = temp.shape[0]
        firstone = temp.at[0, 'Current']
        lastone = temp.at[n - 1, 'Current']
        if n>20:
            if firstone>lastone:
                temp.to_csv(\
                    "C:\\down\\%04d.csv" %i,\
                    sep=',',index=False, header=None)
                temp = temp.drop(index=temp.index)
            else:
                temp.to_csv(
                    "C:\\up\\%04d.csv" % i, \
                    sep=',', index=False, header=None)
                temp = temp.drop(index=temp.index)
        else:
            temp = temp.drop(index=temp.index)
```

The error is:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\fq20881\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/fq20881/OneDrive - University of Bristol/OneDrive/python code/test.py", line 70, in <module>
    firstone = temp.at[0, 'Current']
  File "C:\Users\fq20881\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2156, in __getitem__
    return super().__getitem__(key)
  File "C:\Users\fq20881\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2103, in __getitem__
    return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
  File "C:\Users\fq20881\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3144, in _get_value
    index = self.index.get_loc(index)
  File "C:\Users\fq20881\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0
```

What is wrong and how do I fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:

```
for i in range(0, int(nrows1)):
    if 0<data1.at[i,'Current']<0.000075:
        temp = pd.DataFrame(temp)
        temp=temp.append(data1.iloc[i,0:2])
    else:
        #temp = np.array(list, dtype=float)
        temp = pd.DataFrame(temp)
        n = temp.shape[0]-1
        if n>20:
            if temp.iloc[0,1]>temp.iloc[n,1]:
                temp.to_csv(\
                    "C:\\down\\%04d.csv" %i,\
                    sep=',',index=False, header=None)
                temp = temp.drop(index=temp.index)
            else:
                temp.to_csv(
                    "C:\\Users\\up\\%04d.csv" % i, \
                    sep=',', index=False, header=None)
                temp = temp.drop(index=temp.index)
        else:
            temp = temp.drop(index=temp.index)
```

It seems that the code:

```
firstone = temp.at[0, 'Current']
lastone = temp.at[n - 1, 'Current']
```

cannot find the value I need. Changing it to:

```
temp.iloc[0,1]>temp.iloc[n,1]
```

can solve this problem.